# How do I attach an electric motor to a trailer wheel?

Tags: motors, wheels

I have an electric motor which is intended for a bicycle/scooter and has a 11-teeth chain sprocket. 
I plan to use it to spin a trailer wheel (which have 4 holes for bolts about 3'' from the center). In these cases, do I have to design a mount to attach the wheel to the motor or is it possible to buy a mount that would fit my needs?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Wheel: http://recstuff.com/trailer-tires-wheels/tire-wheel-combos/8-tire-and-rim-packages/4-80x8-loadstar-trailer-tire-lrc-on-4-bolt-galvanized-wheel/
[image]

Comment: you migh fit a small rubber wheel to the motor shaft and drive the outside of the tread.  What drive ratio do you need?

Comment: Are you asking how to mount the wheel directly to the motor shaft? Because if so, first thing is to determine how/if you remove the toothed disc from the shaft

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, that is one of my considerations. The nut is tightly screwed in, but I unscrew it and try getting the sprocket out.

Comment: Late, I know, but depending upon intended use, a [rubber belt pully or chain sprocket centrifugal clutch](https://www.surpluscenter.com/Power-Transmission/Clutches/) might be your best option.   You could probably find one priced between 20 to $30.

Answer (score 1):

Since a scooter has a chain drive and the rear wheel is approximately the same size as some of the small trailer wheels, then you should mount the trailer wheel on an axle with bearings and a sprocket.

Choose the sprocket diameter to give the required speed range as you should know the max rpm of the motor , the dia of the trailer wheel and already the 11 tooth drive...

Comment: I see. May you give me some recommendation for where to buy axles with bearings? The only ones I can find for trailer wheels are axles intended to be fit to a car.

Comment: Look at the design of a scooter axle assembly then design what you need and get a shaft / bearings / supports made / bought as applicable. Not going to suggest shops as where I would consider may not match what you have...